# HTML/Sass: Position of tooltip broken when multi-line

Tags: html, sass, hover, tooltip

I have the following code for a tooltip in my current project:

HTML:

```
<div class="tooltip">
  <img class="icons" src="(...)" alt="Icon"/>
  <span class="tooltip--text">
    Hover-Text
    <span class="tooltip--text--arrow"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Sass:

```
  &--tooltip {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;

    &:hover {
      .tooltip--text {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }

    &--text {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      visibility: hidden;
      width: 120px;
      max-width: 200px;
      background-color: #000;
      color: #fff;
      text-align: center;
      border-radius: 4px;
      padding: 3px 8px;
      margin-top: -3px;
      opacity: 0;
      transition: .3s;
      top: -45%;
      left: 45%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);


      &--arrow {
        position: absolute;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-color: transparent;
        border-style: solid;
        bottom: -5px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -5px;
        border-width: 5px 5px 0;
        border-top-color: #000
      }
    }
  }
```

As long as the text of the tooltip is in one line, everything works perfect as needed. But when the tooltip has more lines, the position of the tooltip is wrong and I don't know how to fix that.

[image: One line tooltip example]  [image: Two lines tooltip example]

Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance!

Comment: You can change `top: -45%` with `bottom: -100%` and adjust the transform property to move up only the height of the arrow: `transform: translate(-50%, -5px)`;

Answer (score 1):

```
.tooltip--text {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    max-width: 200px;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 3px 8px;
    margin-top: -3px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .3s;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 45%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).